# Importing JSON Response into model error Ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ember-router

Here is the code app/routes/profile.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
    model: function() {
        var _this = this;
        return Ember.$.get('/user/profile').then(function(data) 
            _this.store.push('profile', data);
        });
    }
});
```

app/models/profile.js

```
import DS from "ember-data";


export default DS.Model.extend({
    name:   DS.belongsTo('name')

});
```

app/models/name.js

```
import DS from "ember-data";


export default DS.Model.extend({
    firstName:   DS.attr('string'),
    lastName:   DS.attr('string')
});
```

app/serializers/profile.js

```
import DS from "ember-data";

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
    attrs: {
        name: {embedded: 'always'}
    }
});
```

I'm getting an error cannot read property 'typeKey' of undefined

This is the JSON response from server.

```
{
    "id":"1",
    "name":{
        "id":"1",
        "firstName":"first name",
        "lastName":"last name"
    }       
}
```

Comment: Is `data.profile` an array? It seems like it should be a single object, in which case I'm not clear on why `map` is needed here.

Comment: I updated the code.  I'm getting an error of Cannot read property 'typeKey' of undefined

Comment: you dont seem to have the other side of the belongs to relationship set anywhere. http://emberjs.com/guides/models/defining-models/#toc_defining-relationships

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the server to return the payload wrapped in a type object:

```
{
    "profiles": [{
        "id":"1",
        "name":{
            "id":"1",
            "firstName":"first name",
            "lastName":"last name"
        }       
    }]
}
```